# How to set width of elements by relative ratio?

Tags: html, css

For example, I want to set the ratio of width of red:green:blue be 1:2:1 relative to parent, I tried using em, which seems got my desired result:

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:50px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:red;width:1em;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:green;width:2em;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:blue;width:1em;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but the element doesn't disappear when it has 0em:

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:50px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:red;width:1em;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:green;width:0em;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:blue;width:1em;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And according to the description of em, it seems unlikely used to define the relative width/height of element.

Is using em the correct way?If not, what is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can try Viewport sizes :https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: The beginning of the “right way” would probably be to stop using tables for layout purposes first of all (unless you are trying to display actual tabular data here, but there is no indication of that so far.) Tables have their own layout algorithm, that you can take partial influence on (mainly via `table-layout`) - but trying to create a table with 100% width and then three 1em/0/1em sized columns in it, is a rather absurd thing to begin with. Depending on what you actually want to achieve here, stuff like flexbox might be a much better option.

Comment: em is relative to font-size (of the parent element), so if you increased the font-size you'd also see your elements increase in size - try it out and see. vw or %ages would probably be more suitable here.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "cell-padding" simply give your table cell `td` a `padding: 0;`

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:50px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:red;width:1em;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:green;width:0em;padding: 0;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:blue;width:1em;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: After reading your post again, what you're searching for is percentage. This will allow you to use a percentage of the parents width.

A 1:2:1 ratio will be 25% : 50% : 25%

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:50px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:red;width:25%;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:green;width:50%;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:blue;width:25%;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `em` you can use `%`. check snippet below. Also add `cellpadding="0"`

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:50px;" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:red;width:25%;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:green;width:50%;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:blue;width:25%;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> or you can go with `flexbox`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
}
li {
  flex-grow:1;
}
li.double {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li style="background-color:red;">1</li>
<li class="double" style="background-color:green;">2</li>
<li style="background-color:blue;">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `vw` only works if the container fills the width of the whole page. "Viewport width"

Comment: Another note: A total of 40vw wouldn't work if it weren't a table in this case. The same layout with divs would simply fill 40% of the page. You'd need to use `25vw 50vw 25vw` since a full page has `100vw`

Answer (score 0):

Table element has cellspacing and cellpadding. Set cellpadding="0" like following. It will resolve your issue.

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:50px;" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:red;width:1em;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:green;width:0em;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:blue;width:1em;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:50px;border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:red;width:50%;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:green;width:0;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:blue;width:50%;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would insist not using tables for layout purposes and instead use divs but for your answer

```html
<table style="width:100%;height:50px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:red;width:50%;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:green;width:0;">
    </td>
    <td style="height:100%;background-color:blue;width:50%;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```